# how can i fix Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 324 error

Tags: transactions, metamask

my transaction statuse is success but i have this error on all of zksynk era mainnet project (  )Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 324

how can i fix it ?

block expelorer says Unable to decode input data (Contract not verified)

When I connect my wallet to work on ZK network, I always get an error ( Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 324 ) and it says that there is no resolver for your transaction.